# Resizing image error with gm package of node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying this for a while, but I keep getting the error:

```
Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - /images
```

I installed ImageMagick and the gm package, so that's definitely not the problem.

```
    gm(imageLocation)
      .resize(100) // use your own width and height
      .write('here.jpg', function (err) {
        if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
        else console.log(err); 
      });
```

`imageLocation` being `./images/3.jpg`. Why does this error keep happening? I looked at the documentation

I'm on a Windows 32 bit machine. My server is supposed to get an image from a folder, resize it, and then display it. It seems like I have to write the resized photo and then display that, but the writing process always errors out and the image ends up being empty.

If there's a way to skip the writing part and just displaying the photo directly, that would be awesome too.

Thanks!

---

URL Query I used: `http://localhost:8123/images/3.jpg`

Complete code:

```
var querystring = require('querystring'); //used for parsing parts of urls
    url = require('url'); 
    http = require('http'); 
    fs = require('fs'); 
    gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });; 

var server = http.createServer(); 

server.on('request', function(request, response){
    var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url, true); //true gets the query as well

    imageLocation = '.' + parsed_url.pathname;
    gm(imageLocation)
      .resize(100) // use your own width and height
      .write('here.jpg', function (err) {
        if (!err) console.log(' hooray! ');
        else console.log(err); 
      });


    if (getImage('here.jpg', response)){
        //image is displayed 
    }
    else{
    respond404(parsed_url.pathname, response); 
    }

})

function respond404(path, response){
    respond(404, "The requested path " + path + " was not found", response)  
}

function getImage(location, response)
{
    try{
        var img = fs.readFileSync(location);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'image/jpg'}); //parse this end
        response.end(img, 'binary');
        return true;
    }catch(e){
        return false; 
    }    
}

server.listen(8123);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code to work by changing how you required gm as follows:

```
var gm = require('gm');
```

I also had to remember to execute node with the correct permissions in my case:

```
sudo node server.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer Svbaker put can be used in Linux (maybe Mac as well?)

For Windows I got it to work by opening the `command line` in `administrator mode` and starting my server there.